# Multiple ActionListeners in one class

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I'd like to have multiple `ActionListener`'s in my class. I'm making a simple game for a project that has 3 different levels, and a certain amount of buttons in each level.

After each level a new element or component is added. My first level has 25 buttons that when one is pushed they'll emit a random outcome which adds to your score. All these buttons do the same thing so I decided to use an `ActionListener` instead of having to write out 10 `if` statements per button. Problem being I want to do that with my second level but the class already has a defined action performed.

Is there any possible way to have more than one `ActionListener` in the same class?

Here is my `ActionPerformed` method:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     JButton source = (JButton)e.getSource();

        Random RG = new Random();
        level_1_random_block = (RG.nextInt(6));

        frame2.setVisible(false);
        if (level_1_random_block == 0){
            source.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Liam\\Desktop\\BOMB GAME\\oreDiamond.png"));
            score += 100;
            initialize_score();
        }
        if (level_1_random_block == 1){
            source.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Liam\\Desktop\\BOMB GAME\\oreGold.png"));
            score += 25;
            initialize_score();
        }
        if (level_1_random_block == 2){
            source.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Liam\\Desktop\\BOMB GAME\\oreGold.png"));
            score += 25;
            initialize_score();
        }
        if (level_1_random_block == 3){
            source.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Liam\\Desktop\\BOMB GAME\\oreIron.png"));
            score += 5;
            initialize_score();
        }
        if (level_1_random_block == 4){
            source.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Liam\\Desktop\\BOMB GAME\\oreIron.png"));
            score += 5;
            initialize_score();
        }
        if (level_1_random_block == 5){
            source.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Liam\\Desktop\\BOMB GAME\\creeper.png"));
            score -= 30;
            initialize_score();

            try {
                Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Liam\\Desktop\\BOMB GAME\\creeper_sound.wav")));
                clip.start();
            }
            catch (Exception exc){

            }

        }
        if (level_1_random_block == 6){
            source.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Liam\\Desktop\\BOMB GAME\\creeper.png"));
            score -= 30;
            initialize_score();
        }

        source.removeActionListener((ActionListener) this);
        level_1_move_on = true;
        continue_game();

}
public void EventHandler(int level_1_random_block) {
   this.level_1_random_block = level_1_random_block;    
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you want to use a [Strategy Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_design_pattern) to allow the one ActionListener to have different actions depending on the state of the program.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an Inner Class:

`button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ */Code goes here*/
}
})`
(save the actionListener in a variable and set it for many buttons)

Do this multiple times for different buttons and you have multipleActionListeners.

You can also set action commands.
`button.setActionCommad("lvl1");`

In your `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` you can check with if:
`if(e.getActionCommand.equals("lvl1")) { /*code*/ }`

Comment: what do you mean with resolved? getActionCommand returns the String set for the component before with setActionCommand.